# AWS Quicksight Create Dashboard BOTO3 API Call Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, dashboard, amazon-quicksight

I am using boto3 with AWS lambda to create quicksight datasets and create dashboard. In dashboard I am using CUDOS template(publicly available). Datasets are getting created successfully but the creation of dashboard is failing with below error.

```
"Errors": [
  {
    "Type": "ACCESS_DENIED",
    "Message": "You do not have permissions to access the source"
  }
],
```

If I run command from cloudshell the dashboard gets created without any issue. Not sure why its giving issue with lambda function when I tried to give access of datasets to lambda function execution role I get below error
"only QuickSight principals are supported at this point" Invalid principal

Could anyone please help what could be the issue with BOTO3 API access? Thanks !

Comment: Welcome to SO! it sounds like you may have your Principals and Resources on your IAM Policies mixed up. Please provide a sample of your IAM Policies and on what roles they are attached to (obfuscating the sensitive information of course) so we can diagnose this and provide help - in addition you might want to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to see how best to ask a question to gain answers on SO

Comment: Thanks for replying. I am calling Create_dashbaord from AWS lambda. I have given full access(administrator) to Lambda execution role. The template ARN which I am using in create_dashboard boto3 call is of CUDOS(publicly available https://cudos.workshop.aws/)
"Arn": "arn:aws:quicksight:us-east-1:223485597511:template/cudos_dashboard_v3"

When I try to create the dashboard using cli command(cloud shell) it works fine, however when I try the same operation from AWS lambda I get the above error. I am just curious how the access to template works fine with CLI but not with AWS lambda.

Comment: Because IAM Policy documents have two fields that are important here. Principle and Resource. Principle tells the Role that has this Policy Document attached who can use it. If your Principle is set to a user, then the user can use it (and the cli by extension as it uses your user login info). The Resource property tells the Policy Document what resources this policy can interact with. given your error, it seems you are attempting to give the Quicksight permissions onto the Lambda policy - but those must go on the policy of Quicksight, with the resources property giving lambda access

Comment: this is why I asked that you edit your question and add your various (but obfuscated of course) IAM Policies involved. At least one of them is either not providing the Allow it needs to or specifically denying (AWS Permissions are all implicitly denied, but an Explicit Deny always overrides any Explicit Allow) or some other field is missing that is causing the problem - At SO we need to be able to reproduce the problem to help, and that means providing the proper examples of your structures

Comment: Thanks for your response . Below is the IAM policy attached to Lambda role4              {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "*",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
} .. I tried an alternative solution. I cloned the template from CUDOS account to my organization account and Lambda is able to access the cloned template. Not sure if there were any restriction from CUODS account's end.

Comment: can anyone help on how to create RDS dataset for quicksight using boto3 python script

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment you left with your iam policy, you have nothing in Resource. You need at least `"Resource": "*"` - the star being a wildcard to say any resource can make use of this effect.

Similarly, you have nothing in Action, so its not telling the policy any actions that are allowed. You have to have at least `"*"` there as well.

Now, best practice says to give only least permissions possible you should have

`"Action": "the:Action", "Resource": "the:arn:of:the:specific:resource"` or at least as close as you can make it for both of those.

As you also mention, you have an organization account. The controll of those organization accounts can place restrictions on what the sub accounts can and cannot access and put borders on what various resources are allowed to do in the sub account. You may need to check with your sys admins on what is or isnt allowed, and work with them to open it up if you need to.